# Split exact categories arising naturally

Tags: homological-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, exact-categories

If you're interested in the $K$-theory of rings, a useful feature of the exact category of finitely generated projective (or free) modules is that it is *split exact*, i.e. every short exact sequence is isomorphic to a canonical direct sum short exact sequence
$$P' \stackrel{i_{1}}{\rightarrowtail} P' \oplus P'' \stackrel{\pi_{2}}{\twoheadrightarrow} P''.$$
Such split exact categories are often simpler to work with than general exact categories. For example, if $\mathcal{P}$ is a split exact category then $K_{1}\mathcal{P}$ agrees with the Bass $K$-theory group $K_{1}^{\text{Bass}}\mathcal{P}$.

When working with split exact categories I usually have categories of f.g. projective (or free) modules in mind. This can cause problems, or make it hard to look for counterexamples to certain statements, as categories of projective modules have stronger properties that do not hold in a general split exact category. I want to broaden my intuition with some more examples.

One can give numerous examples by cheating, since every additive category can be considered as a split exact category with the minimal exact structure (the one comprised of all sequences isomorphic to the direct sum sequences), but this is not usually the natural choice of exact structure.

> **Question:** What are some examples of split exact categories arising naturally, and which are not equivalent to a category of projective or free modules over some ring?

Comment: Is there any significance to the subscripts in the short exact sequence?

Comment: @Tait the $i_{1}$ is inclusion of the first summand and the $\pi_{2}$ is projection of the second summand.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, pehaps on purpose: "arising naturally" is not the same as "appearing in nature". If designed to attract more attention, it works!

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg I was using them interchangeably, but you're right, they don't mean the same thing. I've changed to title to prevent anyone else being misled :)

Comment: Do you consider it natural to consider finitely generated projective modules over an arbitrary $\text{Ab}$-enriched category? These shouldn't be equivalent to a category of modules over a ring if the category you start with has infinitely many objects. ("Finitely generated" means "admits an epimorphism from a finite coproduct of representables." Projective has the same meaning as usual.)

Comment: Isn't it true that any karoubian split exact category is equivalent to the category of projective modules over a ring?

Comment: @FernandoMuro I'm not sure. I can't think of any (small) examples that aren't equivalent, but I don't see how to prove that every karoubian split exact category is. Presumably you use both embedding theorems to land in a module category, but I don't see why the image is contained in the projectives.